# Nested STL datastructure

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, vector, std

Actually i face problem in case of nested Stl in c++ ,that is how to traverse the nested stl .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
#include<map>
using namespace std;
int main(void) 
{
    vector< vector<int> > vc;
    vector<int> vc1;
    map<int , list<int > > mp;
}
```

Now how can i take input in  `vector < vector <int > >` and print each and every element of `vc` ,
and similarly how can i take input in `map < int , list < int > > mp`
 and print each list corresponding to each key of map .

Comment: In the of simple vector <int> we would traverse like :-             #include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(void){
   vector <int> v(4);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        cin>>v[i];
    }
    vector<int>::iterator itr = v.begin();
    for(;itr!=v.end();itr++){
        cout<<*itr<< " ";
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do that together.
`vector<int> v;`
vector is a wrapper of pure array allocated with a new operator, so its elements can be accessed by applying pointer arithmetic.
`v[i], *(v.begin() +i)` access to i-th element. Indexing from 0.
How to iterate

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.size; i++) cout << v[i] << endl;
for(int x: v) cout << v[i] << endl;
for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) cout << v[i] << endl;
```

Let's take another example
`map<int, list<int> > mp;`
It's not a linear data structure, rather a tree one.
But iteration is similar.
`for(auto node: mp)` where node is `std:: pair<int, list<int>>`
Inside this for loop you can get the `list<int>` with the expression `node.second` and iterate through it in a similar way.

```
for(const auto &node: mp)// node is pair<int, list<int>>
{  int key = node.first;
   cout << key << " ";
   for(auto elem: node.second) // elem is int
      cout << elem << " ";
   cout << endl;
}
```